# How to display unicode characters using curses?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, curses, ruby-1.8

I am currently using this code for a test console, but unicode chars are always completely broken (even more in 1.9 then 1.8.7)

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'curses'

Curses.noecho # do not show typed chars
Curses.nonl # turn off newline translation
Curses.stdscr.keypad(true) # enable arrow keys
Curses.raw # give us all other keys
Curses.stdscr.nodelay = 1 # do not block -> we can use timeouts
Curses.init_screen

count = 0
loop do
  key = Curses.getch || 4294967295
  next if key == 4294967295
  exit if key == 3 # Ctrl+c
  count = (count + 1) % 20
  Curses.setpos(count,0)
  Curses.addstr("#{key.inspect}   äáßðäëéßðf  ");
end
```

any idea how to even partyally fix this (on 1.8 or 1.9) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact steps, but I've heard people say that they had to recompile Ruby using libncursesw5-dev to get Unicode to work as expected.

Comment: seems to work when installing libncursesw5-dev and then reinstalling ruby 1.9 buts its kinda hacky :< (does not work for 1.8.6 or 1.8.7)

Comment: That makes sense, it is a recent addition to the code base so it is probably going to only work with the newest version.  If I understand correctly, this fixes the issue completely for version 1.9 once you get it all installed.  Is that correct? Do you require a fix for 1.8 as well?

Comment: Yep, everything fine in 1.9 after reinstalling, but 1.8 did not benefit at all.

Comment: I think that the library was added after 1.8, so I don't know that you are going to be able to get it working with 1.8 without a lot of effort.